# How do I shorten execution time by replacing the while-loop?

Tags: matrix, while-loop, octave, execution-time

I have written a small code in Octave and part of it is checking whether values in the first rows of two matrices are equal, and if so, adding the value of the second row of the second matrix to the value of the second row of the first matrix.

This is that part of the code that I have written, using a small set of data:

```
PositionLoadArray = 
1    5    3    7    4    6    9    2    1    2
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10

X = 
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

x=1; #row number in matrix X
y=1; #row number in matrix PositionLoadArray

while y<=columns(PositionLoadArray)

   if PositionLoadArray(1,y)==X(1,x) 
      X(2,x)=X(2,x)+PositionLoadArray(,y);
      y=y+1;
      x=1;       
   else    
      x=x+1;    
   endif

endwhile
```

This gives the result:

```
X =
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0   10   18    3    5    2    6    4    0    7
```

The loop runs and works perfectly for small sets like the one above (i.e. where the total number of columns for X and PositionLoadArray (max. values of x and y, respectively) are small). But the loop takes hours to be executed with larger values.

How can I reduce the execution time and get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 X(2, X(1,:) == Y(1,:)) += Y(2, X(1,:) == Y(1,:))
```

Comment: @Matt You're right it isn't.  However, the above code in the question is definitely written in Octave and not MATLAB.  The `columns` function is only available in Octave which returns the total number of columns in a matrix.  I've removed the MATLAB tag.

Comment: @rcpinto That gives me the same result as if my code said 'if PositionLoadArray(1,any(y))==X(1,x)'. Which it did when you read the question. I think the person who edited my question added that part. Do you know how to fix the issue to the question now?

Comment: @rayryeng Nice catch. It's clearly Octave, the OP edited the question accordingly.

Comment: This code would work if `x` wasn't reset to 1 when the `if` condition is satisfied.